# Linked in - multiple test accounts

Tags: testing, linkedin-api, account

i need for my application to create and generate test linked in accounts for every time i run my tests. I have researched and found only this solution which won`t work for me : https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use 2.3   Test Account
You may create up to five LinkedIn test accounts for purposes of testing your Application only. You must create the accounts manually and not via any automated means, such as scripts.

These test accounts must not interact with non-test accounts (for example, you can’t use test accounts to comment to posts on a Company Page and you can’t connect test accounts with non-test accounts, including your LinkedIn account), or override our API call limits. You must clearly identify the accounts as test accounts in the applicable account profile, and must identify these additional account profiles as “Developers” in your Application registration. You may not create any profile positions at real companies (besides your own) through the test accounts.

I will need more than 5 test accounts and also would like to skip the registration of my application into linked in with Real Data...

For facebook integration i managed to make this using https://developers.facebook.com

If someone have any suggestions or solutions please help :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the terms of use you stated in your request, what you are asking for is not available via LinkedIn at the moment.  You will need to change your testing strategy.